# Alerta confirmar eliminar registro

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy aprendiendo y necesito agregar a un sistema de cotizaciones una alerta o venta de confirmación de eliminación de un registro.
Actualmente si por error se presiona ese botón, el registro se elimina directamente.
El fragmento de código es el siguiente:

```html
<tbody>
                <?php foreach ($cotizaciones as $cotizacion) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $cotizacion->id ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo htmlentities($cotizacion->razonSocial) ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo htmlentities($cotizacion->descripcion) ?></td> 
                        <td><?php echo (new DateTime($cotizacion->fecha))->format('d-m-Y'); ?></td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="btn btn-info"
                               href="<?php echo BASE_URL ?>/?p=detalles_caracteristicas_cotizacion&id=<?php echo $cotizacion->id ?>">
                                <i class="fa fa-info"></i>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="btn btn-info"
                               href="<?php echo BASE_URL ?>/?p=imprimir_cotizacion&id=<?php echo $cotizacion->id ?>">
                                <i class="fa fa-print"></i>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
<!--                            <a class="btn btn-warning"
                               href="<?php echo BASE_URL ?>/?p=editar_cotizacion&id=<?php echo $cotizacion->id ?>">
                                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td> -->
                            <a class="btn btn-danger"
                               href="<?php echo BASE_URL ?>/?p=eliminar_cotizacion&id=<?php echo $cotizacion->id ?>&tokenCSRF=<?php echo $tokenCSRF ?>">
                                <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php } ?>
```

Alguien me puede ayudar con el código que tengo que insertar para que aparezca esta confirmación?
Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: No soy experto, lo que he visto que se hace es: en tu botón de elminar muestras un modal, donde pides la confirmación. Obvio el modal tiene 2 botones: si confirma, entonces se ejecuta el código que tienes aquí, el otro botón solo cierra el modal.

Comment: Puedes añadir algo como esto `onclick="return confirm(\'¿Realmente desea eliminar?\')"` si quieres algo sencillo, si quieres algo más vistoso puedes usar Sweetalert por ejemplo.

Comment: podrias llevar a otra pagina que te pregunte y alli hacer un if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta esto, es básicamente lo que te mencionaba en el comentario, una forma muy sencilla de poner la confirmación en un `onclick`. Saludos.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.1/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="tu_url.php" onclick="return confirm('¿Realmente desea eliminar?')"><i class="fas fa-trash mr-2"></i>Eliminar</a>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, me funcionó. Muy agradecido!

Comment: A pesar de que es funcional, es poco elegante y escalable a largo plazo agregar JS directamente en el HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar `confirm` para utilizar los popup del navegador y preguntarle al usuario,  aunque si buscas algo más elegante puedes usar alguna librería de alertas como *alertify js*

```js
deleteButton = document.querySelector('.btn-delete');
deleteButton.onclick = function(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  user_confirm = confirm("¿Está seguro que desea eliminar el registro?")
  if(user_confirm){
    delete_url = deleteButton.getAttribute('href')
    window.location.href = delete_url
  }else{
    alert('La eliminación se ha cancelado')
  }
}
```

```html
<a class="btn-delete" href="http://www.google.cl">
Eliminar
</a>
```

Observación: el `snippet` no te redireccionará, pero el código tomará la url del `href` y si el usuario confirma será redireccionado ahí.

Comment: Gracias, he probado pero no me funcionó.

Comment: Agregaste la clase````btn-delete```` a tu ````a```` que permite eliminar? por que no funciona?

Comment: Seguramente estoy haciendo algo mal.
Te comparto toda esa sección del código. Me ayudas a modificarlo? Sólo me interesa claro la parte del botón eliminar:

Answer (score 0):

```html
<tbody>
                                    <?php
                                    $costoTotal = 0;
                                    $tiempoTotal = 0;
                                    ?>
                                    <?php
                                    foreach ($servicios as $servicio) {
                                        $costoTotal += $servicio->costo;
                                        $tiempoTotal += $servicio->tiempoEnMinutos * $servicio->multiplicador;
                                        ?>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><?php echo htmlentities($servicio->servicio) ?></td>
                                            <td class="text-nowrap">{{<?php echo htmlentities($servicio->costo) ?> |
                                                dinero}}
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                {{<?php echo htmlentities($servicio->tiempoEnMinutos * $servicio->multiplicador) ?>
                                                | minutosATiempo}}
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <a
                                                        class="btn btn-warning"
                                                        href="<?php printf('%s/?p=editar_servicio_de_cotizacion&idCotizacion=%s&idServicio=%s', BASE_URL, $cotizacion->id, $servicio->id) ?>">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                                                </a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <a
                                                        class="btn btn-danger"
                                                        href="<?php printf('%s/?p=eliminar_servicio_de_cotizacion&idCotizacion=%s&tokenCSRF=%s&idServicio=%s', BASE_URL, $cotizacion->id, $tokenCSRF, $servicio->id) ?>">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                                                </a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.1/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="tu_url.php" onclick="return confirm('¿Realmente desea eliminar?')"><i class="fas fa-trash mr-2"></i>Eliminar</a>
```

Esto me soluciono el problema, gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Menciona brevemente _qué hace este código_. Lee [answer], y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.